# Get rows within 30 days where year is current year, month is current month, day is a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have been writing a code to count how many links have been built within 30 days of the clients refresh date where the built links will be archived.

I have been fighting with the code below for hours trying to get it to only select rows where the date is within 30 days of the "refreshday", current month and current year.

My "refreshdate" column is layed out like this: 2017-01-11 00:00:00

What is the best way to do the query?

```
$fulldate = $row["refreshdate"];


$prcount= mysql_query("SELECT linkid FROM linksbuilt WHERE clientid = '$clientid' and linktype = 'PR' and DATEDIFF(day,'$fulldate',getdate()) < 31 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged "mysql" and you are using a MySQL interface (albeit archaic and no longer supported -- switch to `mysqli_`).  So, why are you using SQL Server conventions?

I think the query you want is:

```
SELECT linkid
FROM linksbuilt
WHERE clientid = '$clientid' and
      linktype = 'PR' and
      '$fulldate' >= datesub(now(), interval 30 days);
```

Oh, did I mention that you should use the "mysqli_" interface and use parameters for constants in the query, rather than munging the query string.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!
sorry if i am being a bit of a noob but i've just started learning PHP my plan was to write it in mysql as there is more support for it then convert it to mysqli_ once the project is finished.

I tried the SQL query you provided but it didn't seem to work, is that query getting the current year and month then using just the day from $fulldate   like this  yyyy/mm/$fulldate

Comment: @Harry-Robinson Abandon that plan. Learn mysqli and/or PDO

Comment: @Harry-Robinson . . . If you are learning PHP and MySQL, learn it correctly.  That would be the mysqli_ interface.

Comment: Okay, i will start converting the system to mysqli_ tonight, however i will still be stumped by the original question, has anyone got a mysqli_ solution to the link date query?